# JMeter: Reduce CPU and Internet Bandwidth, not working

Tags: jmeter

I want to test my website's main pages like homepage, payment page, registration page in lower bandwidth. For that, I have tried this tutorial https://qautomation.blog/2019/05/29/how-to-simulate-network-bandwidth-in-jmeter/ and the command is

`jmeter -httpclient.socket.http.cps=<cps value> -n -t <path of .jmx>`

Here I tried CPS values 64, 128, 256 but minimum, maximum, and throughput values are always the same, in the aggregate report.

Am I doing something wrong?
Also, how can I increase or decrease CPU allocation in the same command?

Answer (score 0):

1. You miss `-J` key which is used to [pass a JMeter Property via command-line override](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
2. Depending on the protocol you're using you might need to add another property for [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https)

Assuming all above:

```
jmeter -Jhttpclient.socket.http.cps=xxx -Jhttpclient.socket.https.cps=xxx -n -t <path of .jmx>
```

See [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test) for more detailed and somehow correct steps.

With regards to "decrease CPU allocation" - follow [Reducing resource requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) of the [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html). If you still lack CPU - consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html). If you cannot get another machine and still need to reduce CPU usage - look for the way of changing [CPU affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) for your OS but be aware that in this case the throughput will decrease as well